# Blender won't start

Tags: error

I just downloaded blender on my computer and when I try to open it command line window first opens and then blender opens but it is just white. In the command line window  it says:

> UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000 hz instead
>   Found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\python
>   Blender quit

I don't know what to do.

Comment: What graphic card do you use? Did you try updating or rolling back drivers for it? What is written in the console (command line) is totally ok except for "Blender quit" but it doesn't explain why quitting

Comment: use a GTX 970m. Have updated the driver but it didn't work.

Comment: try restarting the computer, if that fails try uninstalling and deleting the blender folder completely, then re-install it again

Comment: have tried that a couple of times and it won't work

Comment: I discovered if i scale the completely with window of blender it work. But it's so small I can't see anything